# Using Catalyst without command line

Tags: perl, shell, catalyst

Can Catalyst Perl framework be adequately used by developers without command line access to our server? (only with uploading/downloading files facility)

Development happens on the server and doing it on developers' PCs is probably not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Doing any kind of moderately complex development when the only environment you can run code in is a remote server with access only via FTP is a terrible idea. A far better approach to the problem would be to set up local development environments (e.g. in a virtual machine) for each developer.

That said, so long as you can configure the server appropriately in advance (e.g. installing all the Perl module dependencies and setting up the HTTPD to use CGI), then it is possible. You just need to provide a means of restarting the Catalyst application on demand.

One way to do that would be to use plain old CGI to run it (there is a [plack handler for that purpose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::CGI)). That will restart the application for each request, which is terribly inefficient but might work for you.

Comment: Any application with a non-zero number of developers needs a version control system and an environment for development/testing. Hacking away directly on the server is a recipe for disaster. Cannot agree enough with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have SSH enabled, try `rsync` to copy files from one point to another.
It can use SSH but I believe it does not *require* SSH and may use another method such as a remote shell.

See [rsync home page](https://rsync.samba.org/) for further information.

There is also `csync` which uses HTTP.

See [csync home page](https://www.csync.org/)

Comment: The development happens on the server. IDE does not matter for my question. My question is whether it is possible to do development entirely on the server (with any file uploader on the client, be it Padre or something other)

Comment: Is it not possible to put the environment I suggested on the server and then, via a SSH session ( e.g.  puTTy X tunneling ) do your development? I'm just trying help and avoid the command line as you suggested you wanted to do. I have used a similar setup with Eclipse IDE on the server and was able to make Perl code changes thereby bypassing the command line. Once again, just trying to help with some suggestions from my experience. Thx.

Comment: The question is what can we do if there is not possible using SSH.

Comment: @bart: We use FTP :-(

Comment: I didn't see in the question that SSH was unavailable. How about using FileZilla?

Comment: @tale852150 on "I didn't see in the question that SSH was unavailable" see "without command line access to our server" in the question. We use FileZilla and similar clients (personally I use a text editor with FTP support)

Comment: Without SSH up and running on your server I can only suggest FileZilla or some FTP client.  Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: I've updated my answer in the hopes that will help you in some way. Thanks for your patience.  Best of luck.